# XPath boolean 'or'

Tags: xpath

I'd like to select a node if it has `class="something"` or `class="else"`. How can I do that? XPath docs don't seem to contain any easy to find boolean `or` equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `or` operateor is named `or` and you would use it like `//div[@class='something' or @class='else']`

Answer (score 1):

It is just **[`or`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#prod-xpath-OrExpr)**  --  not OR or Or.

**XPath is case sensitive** -- don't forget.